# Histogram in R Plotly: set number of breaks

Tags: r, plotly, histogram

I would like to choose the number of breaks for a plotly histogram in R like the option "breaks" in hist base R.

Data

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
```

Base R

```
hist(x,breaks = 50)
```

pltoly

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = ~x, type = "histogram") # how to add breaks option ?
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The docs for `plot_ly` say to look up additional arguments that can be passed to specific plot types for the underlying javascript functions; the package has a function `schema` to get the plotly.js docs for you. From the docs, it seems like your relevant argument is [`nbinsx`](https://plotly.com/r/reference/histogram/#histogram-nbinsx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = ~x, type = "histogram", nbinsx = 30)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but nbinsx is for a maximal number of bins not for the exact number. However, I can use xaxis.size for the size of bins but I found nothing for the exact number.

Answer (score 1):

I found a custom solution with the xaxis.size option

```
plot_ly(x = ~x, type = "histogram", xaxis = list(size = diff(range(x))/50))
```